# add background color to thumbnail

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am using a thumbnail where the `cross` is transparent and takes the background color of the main `container`. I want the cross to be white.

```
export const FriendDetailsScreen: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeAreaViewContainer}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.iconsContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.cross}>
          <Thumbnail
            source={{
              uri:
                'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/very-basic-android-l-lollipop-icon-pack/24/close-512.png',
            }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  safeAreaViewContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#323443',
    flex: 1,
  },
cross: {
    paddingTop: moderateScale(30),
    paddingLeft: moderateScale(20),
    zIndex: 100,
  },

});
```

If I add a background color to `cross` or the `TouchableOpacity` a block of white appears which goes beyond the thumbnail. How else can I achieve this?

Thumbnail:
https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/very-basic-android-l-lollipop-icon-pack/24/close-512.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing in a style prop to thumbnail like this?

```
export const FriendDetailsScreen: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeAreaViewContainer}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.iconsContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.cross}>
          <Thumbnail
            style={styles.thumbnail}
            source={{
              uri:
                'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/very-basic-android-l-lollipop-icon-pack/24/close-512.png',
            }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  safeAreaViewContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#323443',
    flex: 1,
  },
cross: {
    paddingTop: moderateScale(30),
    paddingLeft: moderateScale(20),
    zIndex: 100,
  },
thumbnail: {
    backgroundColor: '#323443'
  }

});
```